# How to provide blank space between time and date in date filter

Tags: php, twig

I have the following code

```
 {{ "now"|date("h:i  A  d,  F Y ","America/Denver") }} MDT
```

This uses twig PHP for giving time and date. What I want to achieve is give space between A and d. How can i achieve this. I tried &nbsp but was not successful. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape characters. Try something like: `&\nb\sp;`

Comment: You can use day() and time() functions separately and concat result by space

Comment: Not working with &\nb\sp

Answer (score 0):

you have nothing to do for space in date filter

ref: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the characters that are part of the html entity, so that they are ignored by PHP's `\DateTime::format()` used internally by twig. However if you want to store the format string in a variable to be passed to twig's `|date()` filter, you will also need to escape the escapement characters (`\`) and then chain `date` with `raw`:

```
{% set date_fmt = 'M&\\n\\b\\s\\p;jS' %}

{{ 'now'|date(date_fmt) }} <!-- renders html:"Dec&amp;nbsp;6th" reads:"Dec&nbsp;6th" -->

{{ 'now'|date(date_fmt)|raw }} <!-- renders html:"Dec&nbsp;6th" reads:"Dec 6th" -->
```